# Why Jinja2 Set statement is not working in Airflow?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

Let's say I have a dummy operator that has a templatable field. 
Here is the template

```
{% set my_variable = 1 %}
{% if my_variable > 0 %}
foo
{% else %}
bar
{% endif %}
```

If I try to render this task

```
airflow render my_dag my_dummy_task 2019
```

I have an error saying that my_variable is not defined. 
A solution would be to add `my_variable` to the DAG's `params` parameter
and reference it in the template as `params.my_variable` not `my_variable`

```
DAG(dag_id='my_dag',
    ...
    params={
            'my_variable': 1
           },
    ...)
```

I can do that, but I want the variable definition to be in the template using  the jinja2 `set` statement. Is there any way to do so ?